# How to make checkboxes from taxonomy terms?

Tags: taxonomy, select

I can populate selectbox options like this:

```
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => array(
                'country',
            ),
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'name' => 'country'
        );
    ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
```

But the problem is how to make a checkbox list instead of a dropdown?

I mean something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$taxonomy     = 'training_cats';
 $orderby      = 'name'; 
 $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
 $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
 $hierarchical = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
 $title        = '';
 $empty        = 0;
 $args = array(
  'name'     => $taxonomy,
  'orderby'      => $orderby,
  'show_count'   => $show_count,
  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
  'title_li'     => $title,
  'hide_empty'   => $empty
);
$cats = get_taxonomies($args);
foreach ( $cats as $cats2 ) {
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_id" value="'.$cats2->name.'" />';
 echo $cats2-name;
}
```

Not tested but should work, change the taxonomy name etc :)

Edit: Try the new code, using get_taxonomies (the code didn't know where to pull data from)

Edit2: Changed taxonomy to name:

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the checkboxes are 1 more than it should. Eg. I have 6 tags and 7 checkboxes are shown. The second problem is that $cats2->name shows nothing ;(. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: And if I `print_r($cats2)` it shows `post_tag` instad of an array or object. I guess I need to get the taxonomy tags into the array $cats first, like the function `wp_dropdown_categories($args)` is doing. Any idea how t odo that?

Comment: just edited my code, see if that works

Comment: Hmm, I get an empty array now ;( `Array ( )`. Probably the get_taxonomies function has different arguments or order of them? Any idea?

Comment: another edit done, instead of calling taxonomy use name (line 9)

Comment: Still not working. If I try to print_r($cats) after get_taxonomies I am getting an empty array `Array ( )`

Comment: Any idea why it is not working? ;(

Comment: I tried get_terms( $taxonomy, $args ) and seems to be working, but I am not sure 100%. I will test it.